# Logging on to Ubuntu after new install

Tags: password

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 four times. After each installation I attempted to log in by clicking log-in instead of guest. In this field I typed the user name and password I established at the beginning of each installation.

Each and every time I received the error message that my password was invalid. I wrote down each user name and password I established and I verified that each one was correct several times. I made several attempts to log in this way and I was never successful. I can enter as a guest but then I don't have access to administrator privileges so I can connect to my WiFi.

When I try to connect with my WiFi I get the Authentication window and I don't have that password so I get now where. I read through many previous posts on this web site to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question is about a version of Ubuntu that is no longer supported.  Try installing the latest release and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) (resetting the password *should* fix this)

Answer (score 0):

Download [this Ubuntu release](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Unless you need Ubuntu 13.04 for any particular reason, Ubuntu 14.04 should work fine.

Comment: Honestly, its highly un-reccomended to run unsupported releases, even if there is something specific he needs in 13.04, it should be in 14.04.